# Finding pattern of numbers

Tags: mathematics, pattern, formation-of-numbers

I have this puzzle for adding 2 numbers (Or sequences)

Does anyone have an idea about how this addition works?
$$
5+1=9\\3+1=10\\5+2=21\\8+2=23\\9+0=28\\4+3=??
$$

Comment: Care to tell us where this puzzle comes from?

Comment: in fact my friend send it to me

Comment: may be $$ 4 + 3 = 31 $$

Comment: @Mozfox how is that ?

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer can be

> 21

Reason

```
6=9 //5+1=9 
4=10 //3+1=10
7=21 //5+2=21
10=23 //8+2=23
9=28 //9+0=23
7=21 //4+3=21 as already given of 5+2=21
```

Comment: For your second line, it's actually 3+1=10, not 3+2.

Comment: I don't think it's that easy

Comment: @user11618 any hint

Comment: @rudra I don't know why I got downvoted :3 , but I don't think your answer is right

Comment: @user11618 You are downvoted because this is completely random. And the formula submitted by you is not matching with the statement

Answer (score 2):

3+1 = 10 is what’s given. So

> 4 = 10

8+2 = 23. So 10 = 23.

5+2 = 21. So 7 = 21.

> 3 = 10-7 = 23 - 21 = 2

Therefore,

> 4+3 = 10+2 = 12

---

This seems quite improbable but well who knows?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks every body, I've found the solution.
$$
5+2=21 \\
5^2+2^5+(5+2)!=5097 \to 5+0+9+7 = 21\\
x+y = ?\\
x^y + y^x +(x+y)! = abcd \to s= a+b+c+d
$$

Comment: First of all, this is completely random and so far-fetched that I don't believe it's actually solvable.

Comment: Secondly, you've made a mistake: 5^1+1^5+(5+1)!=5+1+720=726 -> 15. Probably 120 was erroneously used instead of 720 by the creator of this puzzle...

Answer (score -2):

Given the formula I get:

> $$4 ^ 3 + 3 ^ 4 + (4 + 3)! = 5185$$
>
>  $$5 + 1 + 8 + 5 = 19$$